# How to track entry visit?

Tags: entry

how do I able to track the visit number of entry?
Something like track view in Expression Engine.

I have try to find but don't have any source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the *Craft Entry Count* plugin by Ben Croker...

> https://github.com/putyourlightson/craft-entry-count

Counting entry views is exactly what that plugin does.

Comment: But it still in private beta =(

Comment: Email him (info@putyourlightson.net) and request to try the private beta version. It's a fairly safe assumption that he wouldn't list it if he didn't want people inquiring about it.

Comment: okie.thank a lot. =)

Comment: i'd be happy to have you in the private beta, just email me!

Comment: For anyone who's late to the party, Counter has been renamed and moved here: https://github.com/putyourlightson/craft-entry-count